# "...is checked if it is..."

Tags: tenses, academia

I'm writing a scientific thesis in English but I'm not a native speaker.
I think this sentence is correct, but I am not sure (that's why I ask this here rather than in "Writing") and I think it does not look nice. I am also not sure when I should use which tense. Especially when writing about an experiment I did in the past.

Can someone come up with a nicer way of writing it in an academic style?

> The poured amount is then checked if it is above zero before being added to the trajectory list.

(For more background what this sentence is about: *The poured amount* in this case is a variable in a program. Obviously it should be above zero, but in case there is an error of some sort its value is checked just to be sure it's really above zero.)

Comment: On the question's face value, **the poured amount** would be better as **the amount poured**. But logically how can **the amount poured** be *less than zero*, unless it flows back into the flask/jug? Did you mean to say "the ***temperature*** of the amount poured" is above zero?

Comment: @WeatherVane It can be below zero if there is a mistake of some sort - this is an error check. "The poured amount" is actually a variable in a program.

Comment: "If the computed amount poured is above zero it is added to the trajectory list, otherwise it is a false result, and ignored."

Comment: @WeatherVane I love this! I'd accept it if you post this as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence could be written as

> If the computed amount poured is above zero it is added to the
>   trajectory list, otherwise it is a false result, and ignored.

Please note I also reversed the order of "poured amount" to "amount poured" to be more idiomatic.